# Prove that it is a quotient map

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

Problem : Prove that the map $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by :

$f(x,y)=y^3+xy^2+x+y$

is a quotient map.

My attempt : Surjecctive part is clear. Now at first I note that the map $g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ defind by $g(x)=ax+b$ is continuous. Next I note that the maps $g_1 , g_2:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $g_1(x)=x^3+x$ and $g_2(x)=x^2+1$ are continuous. Now can I in any way use the fact that composition of quotient maps is a quotient map to prove the result. Any other technique to solve the problem will also be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean [this quotient map](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27066/quotient-map-in-polynomial-ring) ? What is your definition of "quotient map" ?

Comment: @DietrichBurde In topology $q:X\to Y$ is a quotient map if it is surjective, continuous and  continuity of $f\circ q$ implies continuity of $f$.

Comment: Yes, the definitions are equivalent.

Comment: Have a look at the link you gave yourself in order to inform Dietrich. Have a look under "Properties". It is not telling you "how", though. If I find something reachable that does then I will inform you, but at the moment I am not very willing to search for it.

Comment: @DietrichBurde had same question . Surjective and Continuous is clear to me but I am unable to prove that if I take U belonging to R and$ f^{-1}(U) $is open set belonging to $R^{2}$ , then how to prove that U is open in R? Can you please tell. I don't know about submersion as I am doing 1 st course on Topology. –

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $f$ is a submersion ($Df(u,v)=(v^2+1,3v^2+2uv+1)$ and $v^2+1>0$). And sumbmersion is an open map. And $f$ is also surjective. So a surjective open map is a quotient map.

Comment: Yes that might be good but I don't know what is a submersion...I am just a topology beginner.

Comment: Didn't you learn this in multivariate calculus?

Comment: It's good if you know all these...I think in baby Rudin you can find this

Comment: Why did baby Rudin sound funny to you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40950/discussion-between-arghya-chakraborty-and-anubhav-k).

Comment: @AnubhavMukherjee I had same question . Surjective and Continuous is clear to me but I am unable to prove that if I take U belonging to R and $f^{-1}(U)$ is open set belonging to $R^{2} $ , then how to prove that U is open in R? Can you please tell. I don't know about submersion as I am doing 1 st course on Topology.

Comment: @YannicMuller sorry it's been long time. I myself forget what I wrote.

Comment: the definition of open map is that it sends open set to open set. So I guess that is the answer (maybe). I don't remember to be honest.

Comment: @AnubhavMukherjee but how is map f(x, y) open? It's nowwhere proved.

Comment: @AnubhavMukherjee should I ask a separate question?

Comment: as I said, a submersion is an open map. And $f(x,y)$ is a submersion.